# Domino Print Margins

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is there any way to adjust the top and bottom print margins ?

I have attempted to us @Formula and Lotusscript, without any success. I'm hoping there is some kind of trick that I haven't found to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no Print method that lets you specify the margins.  You can open the Print dialog automatically using the formula `@Command( [FilePageSetup] )`.

In the past I've presented a dialog explaining to the user they would need to adjust the margins, and then followed that with the FilePageSetup command to allow them to do so.  Not ideal, but it helped the user along.

Comment: Unfortunately we print in high volume and I was looking for a programmatic solution.

Comment: If you have the users go into File-Page Setup and change their margins, won't it use those settings for all printing from that client?

Comment: @KenPespica So, if someone's doing a lot of printing from Notes, they could just go change their margins before starting to print, right? If they don't print anything from Notes other than the margin-less stuff, they wouldn't ever have to change it. Perhaps a better solution is to figure out how to format the output so that it doesn't require margin-less printing. (If saving paper is the goal, don't print it!)

Answer (score 0):

The form is a document, so the same methods in a document should work.

Select File->Document properties (or application properties). You can assign the header and footer there.

You can get further details from the Infocenter.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.notes85.help.doc%2Fprt_create_header_footer_t.html

Comment: Unfortunately we print in high volume and I was looking for a programmatic solution.

Comment: Didn't have a machine available when I wrote that. This only applies to what you put in the header/footer. Not the size. You could adjust with white space. If you edit the form properties of the document it should change them for all.